SPARQL avg cannot get value

My query here:
PREFIX  om:   <http://www.ontology-of-units-of-measure.org/resource/om-2/>
PREFIX  sosa: <http://www.w3.org/ns/sosa/>

SELECT  (AVG(?value) AS ?avgvalue)
WHERE
  { GRAPH ?g
      { ?speed  sosa:isResultOf       <https://assist-iot.eu/pilot2_rdf/obs/wind_speed> ;
                om:hasNumericalValue  ?value
      }
  }

Actually,The Graph data come from Trig file and I read it and create another GraphMem to store it. If I query the original Graph data, it runs well. Why? Is there wrong with Graph store?

I think it's necessary to show the code here, it's unclear how you create the GraphMem object

I solved this problem, it is caused by Flink serialization.
